# WPF using Web Map displays layers on first run but not second, then third but not fourth

Tags: layers, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net, arcgis-online-webmap

Having a very strange issue with ArcGIS .NET Runtime 100.9 when the WPF app runs for the first time the requested web map and all layers display correctly but when the app is closed and rerun, the web map loads but layers are not displayed.

This pattern repeats, one successful load, then one were the layers fail to display, then success, then failure over & over again on each rerun.

```
TokenCredential token = AuthenticationManager.Current.GenerateCredentialAsync
    (new Uri("https://" + _orgDomain + "/sharing/rest"),
        _userName, _password).Result as ArcGISTokenCredential;

_arcGISOnline = ArcGISPortal.CreateAsync
    (new Uri("https://" + _orgDomain + "/sharing/rest"),
        token, CancellationToken.None).Result;

PortalItem portalItem = await PortalItem.CreateAsync(_arcGISOnline, _itemID);

_map = new Map(portalItem);

await _map.LoadAsync();

Map = _map;
```

The app has been reduced as much as possible and there are very few lines of code left but still can't isolate this strange repetitive behavior.

EDIT: When attaching to the LoadStatusChanged handler I'm seeing a number of layers failing to load with the following 2 errors which appear random: -

> FailedToLoad : System.IO.InvalidDataException: Found invalid data
> while decoding. at System.Net.GZipWrapperStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult)

> FailedToLoad : Esri.ArcGISRuntime.ArcGISRuntimeException: The spatial
> index name is invalid. The spatial index name may be a duplicate name.
> Rename the table to ensure a unique name.

Comment: Interesting, do you have any supporting error message that is retuned or an error log?

Comment: Please use the edit button beneath your question to revise it with the additional error information.

Comment: Error message details added to question as requested.